# Assigning sets of cells in a cell array in MatLab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have data that is divided into multiple types (it depends, usually around 2 - 3 types) in a struct. For example, one might be type A, and be referenced as

```
import.(typeA)
```

or something like

```
currentFields = fieldnames(import);
for i = 1:size(currentFields)
    workingField = import.(currentFields{i})
end
```

This gets me what I need for calling each specific struct, since import is the result of a .json parser

If I know that there are X different sets of data inside each type, and I want to display each piece of the data in a manner such as (assuming x = 3 in this case)

```
Type:    Details:
~~~~~    ~~~~~
type A    123
type A    1.23
type A    12.3
type B    abc
type B    bca
type B    cab
```

Is there any way to call these and put them into a new cell array that doesn't require tons of nested for-loops, such as putting them into a matrix? I was thinking that it could be a simple for-loop with the condition being from 2:(mathematical operation), where the operation is something that calculates that rows 2 - 4 are for type A, and rows 5 - 7 are for type B. I assume that something like modulus would work, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it.

Basically, how do I assign groups of X number of cells (in a column) to each type of a struct using loops, so that the data is easily readable?

```
Thanks in advance!
```

EDIT:

Example data

```
Struct: import
subfields: name, id, date, data [struct]

Struct: data
subfields: left handed [struct], right handed [struct]

Struct: right handed (both left and right have same subfields)
subfields: reaction time, reaction window, position is top (all are numeric values)
```

I want the data to look like this:

```
ID:    Name:    Type:   Reaction T:    Reaction W:   Position is Top:
ABCD   ASH      right      123           130           0
ABCD   ASH      right      180           130           0
ABCD   ASH      left       199           210           1
ABCD   ASH      left       237           270           1
```

where the right handed data is grouped in rows 2 & 3, and the left handed is in 4 & 5. It has to be variable because each dataset is slightly different.

I already have the first 3 columns finished. What I'm most worried about is the last three.

Comment: Can you post a small example of your variables and the result you want?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? I have a struct called import, which has subfields (the first few subfields are just identification information, like ID, date, etc), and one more is a struct with all of the new types of data. For instance, there might be left handed and right handed, each with the same X fields (these fields will go horizontally).

Comment: I mean: post code that we can run, with an example of your variables

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with creating structures, so I can't give code for that ( as this is the output of another script that I didn't write)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a structure array that looks like this

```
data(1).T = 123;
data(1).W = 456;
data(1).P = 789;
data(2).T = 321;
data(2).W = 654;
data(2).P = 987;

data_cell = struct2cell(data);   % Returns 3x1x2 cell array.
```

The first index is specifying field. `data(1).T` correspond to `data_cell{1,1,1}`. `data_cell(1,1,:)` correspond the value contained in field T in all the member of the original structure array. Be careful with {} and () indexing. {} returns content of a cell, whereas () returns a subset cell array

Answer (score 1):

So, you have nested structs that you want in a tabular format? Try the function below. It should work with on structs with the structure you described and convert them to Matlab "table" data types. I guessed on field names, do modify as necessary. To view the table, do `disp(T)`. Not the most elegant, but since your struct is nested with unknown data fields, I'm not sure there's an easier way.

```
function T = nestedStruct2Table(S)
T = table();
nRow = length(S.data.leftHanded);
for i = 1:nRow
    T.ID(i) = S.id;
    T.Name(i) = S.name;
    T.type(i) = 'leftHanded';
    T.reactionT(i)  = S.data.reactionT(i);
    T.reactionW(i)  = S.data.reactionW(i);
    T.posOnTop(i)  = S.data.posOnTop(i);
end

nRow2 = length(S.data.rightHanded);
for i = (1:nRow2) + nRow
    T.ID(i) = S.id;
    T.Name(i) = S.name;
    T.type(i) = 'rightHanded';
    T.reactionT(i)  = S.data.reactionT(i);
    T.reactionW(i)  = S.data.reactionW(i);
    T.posOnTop(i)  = S.data.posOnTop(i);
end
```